# How to scroll down terminal output in watch command

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to see all processes of my computer in real time so I type following command in bash:

```
watch -d -n 1 ps -lax
```

However there are so many processes there is not enough place to display them all in terminal and for some reason while watch is working I cannot scroll down in terminal so I see only few processes that fit into the window. Is there a way to avoid this problem and see all the processes somehow? I'm a Linux newbee btw.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to use top for this purpose =)